# How can I discontinue polyline on Vue.js leaflet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I use vue.js to connected firebase and leaflet and plot polyline but now the problem is I want to discontinue them by referencing their own coordinate.
here is the code

```
<template>
  <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
    <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
    <l-polyline :lat-lngs="coordinate" :color="polyline.color"></l-polyline>
    <l-polyline :lat-lngs="coordinate2" :color="polyline2.color"></l-polyline>
    <l-polyline :lat-lngs="coordinate3" :color="polyline3.color"></l-polyline>
  </l-map>
</template>

<script>
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LPolyline } from "vue2-leaflet";

export default {
  name: "myMap",
  data() {
    return {
      coordinate: [],
      coordinate2: [],
      coordinate3: [],
      url: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      zoom: 20,
      center: [13.754954343896197, 100.47032398711484],
      polyline: { color: "red" },
      polyline2: { color: "lightgreen" },
      polyline3: { color: "blue" },
    };
  },
  firebase() {
    return {
      coordinate: this.$db.ref("/coordinates/"),
      coordinate2: this.$db.ref("/coordinates2/"),
      coordinate3: this.$db.ref("/coordinates3/"),
    };
  },
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LPolyline,
  },
};
</script>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

I have tried many Vue-leaflet plugins (include leaflet decorate) but It can't change color in a segment where I need it.

Comment: It's unclear what data is in the database, and what the result should look like.

Comment: This is database https://imgur.com/hYPiXWi    and This is result look like https://imgur.com/uc4NZS1

Comment: You want 4 polylines (two of them blue) and not 3.

Comment: Actually, Only 3 polylines. Their will have their own color.